# Client cannot pubish because firewall issue with full replication factor

Tags: apache-kafka

Setup: Three Node Kafka cluster running version 2.12-2.3.0. Replication factor is 3 and with 20 partition per topic.

Description:
All three nodes in Kafka cluster can communicate between themself without issue. An incorrect firewall is introduced with Kafka client which "block" client from communicating with one Kafka node. The client can no longer publish to any of the Kafka node. Two Kafka nodes are still network reachable from Kafka client. We understand this is a network split brain issue.

Question: Is there a way to configure Kafka so that kafka client can communicate with "surviving" Kafka nodes?

Answer (score 0):

> The client can no longer publish to any of the Kafka node

That shouldn't happen. The client should only be unable to communicate with *leader partitions* on that one node, and continue communicating with the leader partitions on the other, reachable nodes.

There are no changes you could make on the server-side if the client's host network/firewall is the issue.