# Client cannot pubish because firewall

Tags: apache-kafka

This is a followup question regarding [Client cannot pubish because firewall issue with full replication factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65674424/client-cannot-pubish-because-firewall-issue-with-full-replication-factor)

After another round of testing with different sequence of brokers. e.g.

```
BROKERS="1.2.3.4:9092,3.4.5.6:9092,7.8.9.10:9092" or
BROKERS="3.4.5.6:9092,7.8.9.10:9092,1.2.3.4:9092" 
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list ${BROKERS}  --producer.config prop  --topic test
```

where topic test is configured with 3 partition and replication of 2.

We observe if the 1st node in the BROKERS is network reachable then kafka-console-producer.sh can produce message. However, kafka-console-producer.sh hang if the first broker is not reachable and kafka-console-producer.sh does not try to connect to the 2nd or 3rd broker.

Another observation is that Kafka can consume messages even producer is firewall'ed. Does brokers do topic replication? I am under the impression Kafka client is fully responsible for the topic replication.

Comment: Not sure I follow... As answered there, clients should be able to communicate with all brokers. You cannot decide only one broker should be accessible because you cannot hard-code where a leader partition will exist. If you want to do topic replication, this is commonly done with MirrorMaker

Comment: Also, are you sure the consumer hangs? Or just that there are no messages from the offset you're trying to read for the brokers that _are reachable_? (and that the consumer offsets topic has a replication factor higher than 1 and is not located on the unreachable nodes)

Comment: The "hang" situation is confirmed with netstat -nat | grep :9092. It stay in SYNC state with "firewalled" IP address.